# passing data from parent to child

Tags: objective-c

In my app I'm trying to pass data from the parent view to the child view. However, when I run the app the delegate method isn't being called.
Here is the code on how I implemented the custom delegate:
parent.h

```
    @protocol SLBWallViewControllerDelegate <NSObject>

- (void) pictureToBeUploaded:(id)picture;

@end

@interface SLBWallViewController : UIViewController <UIActionSheetDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate>
- (IBAction)createPotButtonPressed:(id)sender;

@property (weak, nonatomic) id <SLBWallViewControllerDelegate> delegate;
@end
```

parent.m

```
[self.delegate pictureToBeUploaded:info[UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage]];//i'm taking the pic from a uiimagepicker
```

child.h

```
@interface SLBPostViewController : UIViewController <SLBWallViewControllerDelegate>
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *picture;
@end
```

child.m

```
#pragma mark - Wall View Controller Delegate
- (void)pictureToBeUploaded:(id)picture{
    self.picture.image = picture;
}
```

Is there anything wrong or missing?

Comment: Perhaps the `delegate` is `nil` at that point. Where do you initialize & assign it?

Comment: i didn't initialize the delegate, where do i do that?

Comment: Well, since you want to send a message to `self.delegate` it means that you should at some point, before that, have something like `self.delegate = //.. a Child instance`.

Comment: okay thanks! it worked. i gave you a one up if you want post the answer separately and i'll make sure to check it as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the problem probably (**edit:** confirmed in the comments) is that `self.delegate` is `nil` at that point. So you send a message to `nil` and nothing happens of course. What you have to do is make sure that you assign a `Child` instance to `delegate` property before trying to send the message. Something like this for example:

```
//...
self.delegate = //.. a 'Child' instance

//...
[self.delegate pictureToBeUploaded:info[UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage]];
```

Answer (score 0):

**//(1) In Child in .h file create one property**

@property (nonatomic,strong) UIImage * someImage;

**//(2) In Child in .m file override the property**

-(void)setSomeImage:(UIImage *)someImage{

```
_someImage=someImage;
self.picture.image = self.someImage;
```

}

**//(3) In Parent in .m file set image to child's 'someImage' property**

childsObject.someImage= UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage;